# How to determine when the content of database page in Java is being changed?

Tags: java, database

So I have a simpleDB database that is multi-user transactional database server written in Java, which interacts with Java client programs via JDBC. The problem that is that my flush function in my file manager which basically writes data to the a block has unnecessary calls, so I need a flag that basically checks if the page has been modified but not flushed to disk then, flush it, otherwise ignore. My problem is that I am confused if the page is actually modified in more than one method?

I have a variable wasModified to check that. The obvious place to me is the appendval() function because the page is obviously being changed. But apparently, there are still other places where the page is being changed and I can't figure out where.

```
public class LogMgr implements Iterable<BasicLogRecord> {
   /**
    * The location where the pointer to the last integer in the page is.
    * A value of 0 means that the pointer is the first value in the page.
    */
   public static final int LAST_POS = 0;

   private String logfile;
   private Page mypage = new Page();
   private Block currentblk;
   private int currentpos;
   private int increment = 0;
   private boolean wasModified = false;
   /**
    * Creates the manager for the specified log file.
    * If the log file does not yet exist, it is created
    * with an empty first block.
    * This constructor depends on a {@link FileMgr} object
    * that it gets from the method
    * {@link simpledb.server.SimpleDB#fileMgr()}.
    * That object is created during system initialization.
    * Thus this constructor cannot be called until
    * {@link simpledb.server.SimpleDB#initFileMgr(String)}
    * is called first.
    * @param logfile the name of the log file
    */
   public LogMgr(String logfile) {

      this.logfile = logfile;
      int logsize = SimpleDB.fileMgr().size(logfile);
      if (logsize == 0)
         appendNewBlock();
      else {
         currentblk = new Block(logfile, logsize-1);
         mypage.read(currentblk);
         currentpos = getLastRecordPosition() + INT_SIZE;
      }
   }

   /**
    * Ensures that the log records corresponding to the
    * specified LSN has been written to disk.
    * All earlier log records will also be written to disk.
    * @param lsn the LSN of a log record
    */
   public void flush(int lsn) {
      if (lsn >= currentLSN()) {  
          flush();
      }
   }

   /**
    * Returns an iterator for the log records,
    * which will be returned in reverse order starting with the most recent.
    * @see java.lang.Iterable#iterator()
    */
   public synchronized Iterator<BasicLogRecord> iterator() {
      flush();
      return new LogIterator(currentblk);
   }

   /**
    * Appends a log record to the file.
    * The record contains an arbitrary array of strings and integers.
    * The method also writes an integer to the end of each log record whose value
    * is the offset of the corresponding integer for the previous log record.
    * These integers allow log records to be read in reverse order.
    * @param rec the list of values
    * @return the LSN of the final value
    */
   public synchronized int append(Object[] rec) {
      int recsize = INT_SIZE;  // 4 bytes for the integer that points to the previous log record
      for (Object obj : rec)
         recsize += size(obj);
      if (currentpos + recsize >= BLOCK_SIZE){ // the log record doesn't fit,
         flush();        // so move to the next block.
         appendNewBlock();
      }
      for (Object obj : rec)
         appendVal(obj);
      finalizeRecord();
      //int lsn = currentLSN() + (++increment);
       int lsn = currentLSN() ;
      return lsn;
   }

   /**
    * Adds the specified value to the page at the position denoted by
    * currentpos.  Then increments currentpos by the size of the value.
    * @param val the integer or string to be added to the page
    */
   private void appendVal(Object val) {
      if (val instanceof String) {
          mypage.setString(currentpos, (String)val);
          wasModified = true;
      }

      else {
          mypage.setInt(currentpos, (Integer)val);
          wasModified = true;
      }

      currentpos += size(val);
   }

   /**
    * Calculates the size of the specified integer or string.
    * @param val the value
    * @return the size of the value, in bytes
    */
   private int size(Object val) {
      if (val instanceof String) {
         String sval = (String) val;
         return STR_SIZE(sval.length());
      }
      else
         return INT_SIZE;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the LSN of the most recent log record.
    * As implemented, the LSN is the block number where the record is stored.
    * Thus every log record in a block has the same LSN.
    * @return the LSN of the most recent log record
    */
   private int currentLSN() {
      return currentblk.number();
   }

   /**
    * Writes the current page to the log file.
    */
   private void flush() {
       if(wasModified) {
           mypage.write(currentblk);
           wasModified = false;
       }

   }

   /**
    * Clear the current page, and append it to the log file.
    */
   private void appendNewBlock() {
      wasModified = true;
      setLastRecordPosition(0);
      currentpos = INT_SIZE;
      currentblk = mypage.append(logfile);
   }

   /**
    * Sets up a circular chain of pointers to the records in the page.
    * There is an integer added to the end of each log record
    * whose value is the offset of the previous log record.
    * The first four bytes of the page contain an integer whose value
    * is the offset of the integer for the last log record in the page.
    */
   private void finalizeRecord() {
      mypage.setInt(currentpos, getLastRecordPosition());
      setLastRecordPosition(currentpos);
      currentpos += INT_SIZE;
   }

   private int getLastRecordPosition() {
      return mypage.getInt(LAST_POS);
   }

   private void setLastRecordPosition(int pos) {
      mypage.setInt(LAST_POS, pos);
   }
}
```